# Se puede controlar los cambios de mi base de datos en Postgresql con GitHub?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, github, control-de-versiones

Quisiera controlar las versiones/cambios de estructura realizados a mi base de datos que está hecho en postgresql. Se puede conectar con GitHub? o hay otra herramienta similar?

Comment: Cambios en los datos? En las tablas? En el código que usas para crearla?

Comment: Cambios de estructura preferentemente

Comment: lamentablemente tu pregunta tal cual está, cae en el grupo de "Basada en Opiniones" Por otro lado, toma https://dbup.github.io/ esto te ayudará a darle un mejor control a los cambios de tu bd

Comment: @fredyfx que significa esto "lamentablemente tu pregunta tal cual está, cae en el grupo de "Basada en Opiniones""?

Comment: que potencialmente será cerrada porque existen múltiples respuestas que encajan.